# XtraGrid binding inherited object

Tags: c#, binding, xtragrid, derived

I have one base class and 2 inherited classes. According configuration of application must bind Customer1 or Customer2 to XtraGrid:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
}

public class Customer1 : MyBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class Customer2 : MyBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, binding code:

```
    Customer1 c1 = new Customer1();
    c1.ItemID = 1;
    c1.Name = "N1";
    c1.BirthDate = DateTime.Now;

    BindingList<MyBase> tmpList = new BindingList<MyBase>();
    tmpList.Add(c1);

    gridControl1.DataSource = tmpList;
```

But grid display only ItemID field which is derived from MyBase class.

Could you pls help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is - you cannot do that. This is not a specific to the `XtraGrid`, but to all controls that use list data binding. When you use `List<T>`, `BindingList<T>` etc. the typeof(T) is extracted and used as item type to retrieve bindable properties. Note that none of these classes (and `IList<T>` in general) supports variance, so you cannot use the base class as a generic parameter. Just use the concrete class when instantiating List/BindingList which you plan to use as a data source (in your case - `BindingList<Customer1>` or `BindingList<Customer2>`).

Answer (score 0):

You are only seeing the `ItemID` field in your grid because you have added the base class `MyBase` as the type to your `BindingList`.

You should change the type of the `BindingList` to either `Customer1` or `Customer2` in your code.

```
Customer1 c1 = new Customer1();
c1.ItemID = 1;
c1.Name = "N1";
c1.BirthDate = DateTime.Now;

BindingList<Customer1> tmpList = new BindingList<Customer1>();
tmpList.Add(c1);

gridControl1.DataSource = tmpList;
```

Using the base class `MyBase` is restricting the view on the Customer class to just what is available in the base class. So the grid can only see the `ItemID` field.

You will not be able to bind a collection of both `Customer1` and `Customer2` types to the grid. You need to rethink your solution. You could possibly create a class which contains all the fields from `Customer1` and `Customer2` (lets call this `Customer`) and also add an additional field, possibly an enum, that sets the Customer Type (ie. Customer1 or Customer2). Then you can create a binding like this:

```
public enum CustomerType
{
    Customer1,
    Customer2
}

public class Customer
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public CustomerType Type {get; set; }
}

Customer c = new Customer();
c.ItemID = 1;
c.Name = "N1";
c.BirthDate = DateTime.Now;
c.Type = CustomerType.Customer1;

BindingList<Customer> tmpList = new BindingList<Customer>();
tmpList.Add(c);

gridControl1.DataSource = tmpList;
```

You grid will then be able to display all the fields you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time.

I just tried UnBound column type and resolved issue.